# How to know for sure whether cross_validate is using stratified K-fold?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to make sure that `cross_validate` is using a stratified CV. In the [documentation for `cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html?highlight=cross_validate#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate), there is written that

> For int/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either
> binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases,
> KFold is used.

My estimator is a classifier and my dependent variable is binary. So in theory also by setting `cv=None` I should obtain a stratified CV.

How can I be sure of that? How to check whether `cross_validate` here:

```
rfc_score = cross_validate(rfc, desc_tfidf, labels, scoring=metrics)
```

is really using a stratified CV?

Answer (score 2):

From the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L42) of `cross-validate`, we can see that the very [first thing](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L233) run by the method is:

```
cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
```

And in [`check_cv`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2022), we have:

```
cv = 5 if cv is None else cv
if isinstance(cv, numbers.Integral):
    if (classifier and (y is not None) and
            (type_of_target(y) in ('binary', 'multiclass'))):
        return StratifiedKFold(cv)
    else:
        return KFold(cv)
```

which is exactly what the documentation claims.